# Phpmailer to multiple recipients with language include

Tags: php, phpmailer

In order to send an email to multiple recipients, I get the individual user data from the DB and then loop through the results, generate the individualized email template and send it. Now, for each user the preferred language is provided from the DB (either DE or EN). I switch this info and include the corresponding language file. Problem is, all emails arrive in EN although some users are set to "de" in the DB.

```
*PDO SELECT query*

    while ($row_pdo = $stmt_pdo->fetch()) {
        $recipient_name = $row_pdo['recipients_name'];
        $recipient_email = $row_pdo['recipients_email'];
        $recipient_language = $row_pdo['recipients_language'];
        
        switch ($recipient_language) {
            
            case "de":
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/lang/lang_de.php";
            break;
            
            case "en":
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/lang/lang_en.php";
            break;
            
            default:
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/lang/lang_en.php";
            break;
            
        }
        
        require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/view/email/email_template.php';
        
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host       = ...;
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->Username   = ...;
            $mail->Password   = ...;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
            $mail->Port       = ...;
        
            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('.', '...');
            $mail->addAddress($recipient_email);
            $mail->addReplyTo('...', '...');
        
            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = ...;
            $mail->Body    = $htmlemail;
            $mail->AltBody = $htmlemail;
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        
            $mail->send();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }     
        
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();
    }
```

Comment: `email_template.php` is not using the constants from `lang_de.php`

Comment: Anything that's going wrong is happening *before* you attempt to send the email, so concentrate on that. Also, if you're generating HTML in your template, don't put that in a plain-text version as well; you may find it works better if you use `$mail->msgHTML($htmlemail);` instead of setting `Body` and `AltBody` manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The email template is using the constants, this is not the issue. Also I tried what @Synchro suggested, all emails still arrive in EN.

Comment: If they arrive in English, you're telling it to send them in English. Don't assume things are working as you think, **check**. For example, why are you using `include` and not `require`? It failing to load the language file isn't something you're trapping, and your path generation is unusual (`__DIR__` would be more common than `DOCUMENT_ROOT`), so that seems like a prime candidate to me.

Comment: @Synchro I ran these checks, both adapting to require and switching path generation to `__DIR__`. Doesn't seem to be the issue. But if I change the DB language entry for the initial user (first while loop) to "de", all emails arrive in DE. If I output the email html the behaviour is the same. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with phpmailer but with loops 2-n where the language file isn't overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I found the issue. Within the language file, strings are defined using constants. Constants cannot be overwritten within the same script.